# is it possible to have in rage filter option in advanced filtering?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

i'm using the latest version of aggrid in React typescript and i want to use the new feature: advanced filter in aggrid, when i'm working with dates, i don't see the in range option that exists in the basic filter:

[advanced filter without in range filter option for dates:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHnpT.png)

[basic filter with in range filter option for dates:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOe5j.png)

i don't see an example in the docs and i want use this option in the advanced filter bar and in the filter builder as well.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no way to implement this behaviour with AG Grid. However, we have a feature request for this in our backlog and we are tracking it with the following reference: **AG-10029**.